# UI rendering issues with Segmented Control

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I'm working on a simple app to learn Cocoa and I've encountered a *little rendering bug* with the segmented controller.

[image: Buggy]

As you can see here, the view does not display fully opaque. I've looked around to try and find a solution to this to no avail. I did at one point think that maybe this control wasn't supposed to be used in this way but a quick browse through the system preferences yielded several views using this technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control you are looking for is actually NSTabView. Docs here:

[NSTabView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTabView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)